# How to replace mesh data in linked object by another object's linked data?

Tags: mesh

I have two sets of linked objects in the scene and want to "move" some objects from one set to the other without losing the object's potition, orientation and scale.

I other words, I want to replace just the linked mesh data in an object of the second set of linked objects, by the mesh data in one object from the first set of linked objects.

The image below depicts what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the object whose mesh you want to replace, then go to the "Object Data" tab in the properties panel (the one with the triangle standing on one of its vertices). The topmost dropdown menu lets you select the mesh linked to your object. Just select MeshData1 here.
[image]

The little number on the right also tells you how many users your mesh has (to how many objects it is linked).